# Tengo una consulta MySQL de fecha y cuando la ejecuto no me devuelve ningun error ni me devuelve ningun valor

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, date

Tengo la siguiente sentencia en mysql

```
select detalle_v.idp, producto.nombre, count(detalle_v.idp) as cantidad, detalle_v.precio as p_unitario, sum(detalle_v.precio) as total 
from detalle_v inner join producto on detalle_v.idp = producto.idp inner join t_precios on t_precios.idp = detalle_v.idp inner join venta on detalle_v.idv = venta.idv 
where date_format(venta.fecha, '%d-%m-%y') BETWEEN '24-07-2018' and '24-07-2018'
group by detalle_v.idp;
```

al momento de ejecutarla no me marca ningun error pero tampoco me devuelve ningun valor

Comment: en que formato estan guardadas las fechas en tu base de datos?

Comment: cual es el formato de valor de la fecha? deberia ser DATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: el formato de mi base de datos es yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: la fecha si esta en date

Comment: podrias mostrar la Mysql error logs
? para ver que errores se ha producidos?

Comment: no me marca ningun error, la sentencia si se ejecuta pero no me devuelve ningun valor

Comment: Es preciso comprender algo fundamental, para no estar sobrecargando el código: **los formatos sólo son útiles para salida de datos o para manipular valores provenientes del exterior y que deben ser adaptados**. Eso significa que si se trata de un criterio a aplicar en los datos, no vale la pena formatear, es más eficaz pasar los datos  a la BD como ella los tiene. O sea, pon tu criterio así: `where venta.fecha = '2018-07-24'`. Para un criterio como lo es `WHERE`
, formatear no tiene sentido. Además, dado que es el mismo rango de fechas, `BETWEEN` tampoco es necesario.

Answer (score 1):

Principalmente en Mysql se usa el formato `yyyy-MM-dd`, te recomendaría lo siguiente:

```
DATE(venta.fecha) BETWEEN DATE('2018-07-24') and DATE('2018-07-24')
```

entendiendo que venta.fecha es un valor tipo `DATETIME` o `DATE` en la columna

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo porque haces un BETWEEN para NO utilizar un rango de fecha distinto,
por otra parte, yo llamaria a la fecha en el formato que corresponda y luego si quieres mostrarla de forma distinta le cambias el formato en el select,
simplemente tu query la dejaría de esta forma:

```
 select dv.idp, p.nombre, count(dv.idp) as cantidad, dv.precio as 
 p_unitario, sum(dv.precio) as total 
 from detalle_v dv 
 inner join producto p on dv.idp = p.idp 
 inner join t_precios tp on tp.idp = dv.idp 
 inner join venta v on dv.idv = v.idv 
 where v.fecha='2018-07-24'
 group by dv.idp;
```

Ahora si llegas a utilizar un BETWEEN lo haria sabiendo que tengo un rango distinto de fechas:

```
 select dv.idp, p.nombre, count(dv.idp) as cantidad, dv.precio as 
 p_unitario, sum(dv.precio) as total 
 from detalle_v dv 
 inner join producto p on dv.idp = p.idp 
 inner join t_precios tp on tp.idp = dv.idp 
 inner join venta v on dv.idv = v.idv 
 where v.fecha between '2018-07-23' and '2018-07-24'
 group by dv.idp;
```